# Fields not being deleted

Tags: 7, entities

I am having problems on an installation I have got from a new client. I have updated to 7.38 hoping for a fix, but it hasnt helped.

Trying to delete fields manually by enabling them on a content type and then deleting them results in a "The website has encountered an error page".

In the field list at /admin/reports/fields there are 20 or so fields that are not used in any content types.

What is the procedure here? Drupal should delete any inactive fields on a cron run, right? I know I can manually wipe them from the database, but id rather work out the problem so it doesnt happen again. Plus the "website has encountered an error" page is unacceptable when an admin is adding and removing fields.

**Edit: Warnings from watchdog...**

Notice: Undefined index: tabbed_farm_page in field_ui_fields_list() (line 35 of /var/www/website/modules/field_ui/field_ui.admin.inc).

Notice: Undefined index: tabbed_farm_page in _field_ui_bundle_admin_path() (line 325 of /var/www/website/modules/field_ui/field_ui.module).

Comment: _Drupal should delete any inactive fields on a cron run, right?_ Depends what you mean by 'inactive'. Drupal will purge deleted fields, but it won't purge fields that haven't been deleted (for obvious reasons, can you imagine the problems that would cause??). But as you're getting an exception when you try to do it manually, I think it's fair to assume the cron job will be running into the same problem.  You need to check your watchdog/server logs for the real error message, without that you (and anybody else) are just poking in the dark as to what could be wrong

Comment: Yeah fair enough, thanks Clive. I have just updated the question with some watchdog notices its throwing up

Comment: Have you maybe deleted a content type called `tabbed_farm_page`?

Comment: Hi Clive, yes that's correct. And looking at the fields, the majority of fields left over were from that content type. Deleting a content type should also delete the fields though unless they are used elsewhere.

Comment: Just tried deleting another content type i created as a test, and that threw up a "The website encountered an unexpected error. Please try again later." as well :(

Comment: Yikes, looks like the field config is out of whack for whatever reason. No judgement, but have you been editing the field_config or field_config_instance tables manually anytime recently? ;)

Comment: Nope, not me. I just picked up this site, It could be that the last guy was playing with it. I have just added a content type with the machine name tabbed_farm_page and it autopopulated all 20 fields and field sets from the field group module. Obviously they were still assigned in the database

Comment: Ok, every field now has a content type for the "Used in" column in the field list, but trying to delete anything is still throwing up error pages. Eugh. Dont know where to turn here.

Comment: Is there nothing more serious in the watchdog than notices? I can't think of a situation where seeing that error page wouldn't result in a fatal error in the watchdog logs

Comment: Yeah just notices, no fatals.

Comment: ok, finding all sorts of problems here. going to do an overhaul, start fresh with the theme and export nodes and content types manually from the database. Thanks for your help.